# What is the best way to integrate a person's iTunes Library in an Objective-C application?

Tags: objective-c, macos, integration, itunes

I want to integrate the iTunes library into my application so the user can create a series of songs to play for a straight hour, where the song changes every hour. I should have no problem creating the logic for playing the audio files, I just was wondering the best approach to accessing and displaying the contents of the iTunes Library XML file or if there is any other methodology for accessing this data.

Edit: To clarify, I am not talking about integrating into iOS. Simply the OS X platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MPMusicPlayerController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMusicPlayerController_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008221)

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I am talking about integrating into the OS X platform not iOS. I don't think the MPMusicPlayerController class works on OS X, but I may be mistaken.

Comment: Oops. Apologies. I was thinking iOS. There's plenty of functionality to integrate iTunes via AppleScript that may be worth investigating.

Answer (score 0):

You have options.  There's the iTunes Library Framework from Apple, as of several OS versions ago.  Docs are here https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/iTunesLibrary/Reference/iTunesLibraryFrameworkReference/index.html

Here's a sample project I found from other stackexchange answers to similar questions, https://github.com/zadr/iTunesLibraryExample

You should look at the related questions - I think they'll answer a lot more for you, but basically, you have this framework, scripting bridge, or parsing the XML yourself or with someone else's library, like EyeTunes.  I'd suggest giving the Apple framework a shot and filing bugs as needed to prompt them to make it better.

As for actual play control, depends if you are playing the files yourself vs. telling iTunes to play them - but you said you have that under control, so won't say anything besides pointing out the AVFile, AVAsset, etc. classes and controllers related to Core Audio (in addition to Quicktime) for playing files yourself vs. using the scripting bridge to tell iTunes to do so.  The framework is, like the XML file, more for reading iTunes data than for controlling it.